# A Bit of Confusion With AVFoundation

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, avfoundation

So I have been working with AVFoundation for a few weeks now, what a pain!

I have gotten to the point in my camera application where I am trying to save a video being recorded to the photo albums. I have looked around here on google and as it is well known, Apple's documentation is horrible for AVFoundation.

I am not exactly sure how to approach saving a video to the photo albums. I have read quite a few things on how to do it with pictures, but videos are a little bit different, since they need a URL.

The code I have below doesn't quite work. It does reach the `println("Succesfully saved the video to the photo album")`statement, but then afterwards, it crashes with the error

`Succesfully saved the video to the photo album
2015-05-16 19:09:02.371 CopWatch[685:234398] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x183e4e59c 0x19454c0e4 0x183e4e4dc 0x184c90528 0x184c90488 0x18eae665c 0x189f66090 0x100618e30 0x100618df0 0x100623854 0x10061c120 0x10062575c 0x100626f18 0x194d6d2e4 0x194d6cfa8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

I can't quite get the logic right here. I guess my google searching skills aren't up to par for this foundation, it seems very hard to find things on this stuff. Can anybody help me out here?

> Blockquote

```
/**************************************************************************
    DID PRESS CAPTURE
    **************************************************************************/
    @IBAction func didPressCapture(sender: AnyObject) {

        if self.takingVideo == true {

            //------ MAKE SURE WE ARE NOT ALREADY RECORDING ------
            if self.weAreRecording == false {

                println("Taking a video")

                //------ MAKE SURE THE DEVICE IS AUTHORIZED TO TAKE A VIDEO ------
                if self.deviceAuthorized == AVAuthorizationStatus.Authorized {

                    println("Device is authorized to take video")

                    dispatch_async(self.sessionQueue) {

                        println("Getting Video Output Path")

                        //------ GRAB THE OUTPUT FILE URL TO SAVE TO PHOTO ALBUM ------
                        let outputPath = "\(self.documentsPath)/output.mov"

                        self.outputFileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: outputPath)
                        self.session.startRunning()

                        println("Starting to record to output path")

                        self.movieFileOutput!.startRecordingToOutputFileURL(self.outputFileURL!, recordingDelegate: self)

                        self.isSessionRunning = true
                    }
                }
                else {

                    println("Device is not authorized to take video")

                }

                self.weAreRecording = true
            }
            else {

                //------ STOP THE VIDEO, PROCESS THE VIDEO HERE ------
                println("Stopping the video")

                dispatch_async(self.sessionQueue) {

                    println("Stopping the session from recording")

                    //------ STOP RECORDING AND SAVE TO VIDEO TO PHOTO ALBUM ------
                    self.session.stopRunning()
                    self.movieFileOutput!.stopRecording()

                    println("Saving the video to the photo albums")

                    UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(String(contentsOfURL: self.outputFileURL!), nil, nil, nil)

                    println("Succesfully saved the video to the photo album")

                    self.isSessionRunning = false
                }

                self.weAreRecording = false
            }
        }
        else {

            //------ HANDLE TAKING A PICTURE HERE ------
            println("Taking a picture")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing particular to do with AV Foundation, except by a kind of coincidence. The problem is the nature of *asynchronous* methods — and almost everything connected with AVFoundation is asynchronous.

Thus, the fact that you get the console messages in this order:

(1) Succesfully saved the video to the photo album

(2) 2015-05-16 19:09:02.371 CopWatch[685:234398] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'

...is meaningless. UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum is *asynchronous*. That means it takes time (quite a long time, actually) and operates on a background thread. Meanwhile, your main code just proceeds blithely along. *Then*, on its background thread, UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum crashes and burns — presumably because of this confusion with threading.

To straighten this out, start by going back and fixing your call to UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum so that it has a *completion handler*. Do nothing further except in that completion handler. Thus, your `println` will happen in the completion handler, and so you will see for real whether the video was successfully saved.

Comment: I am also not convinced that your use of a special `sessionQueue` is right; this is another invitation to end up with threading issues, it seems to me.

Comment: Thanks for the information! I am not a very good multithreading programmer, my professor I had a long time ago that was supposed to teach us those things never actually did. I also haven't had to work with many thread before so this is a little new to me. I will get rid of the extra queues for now and just simply see if I can get things woking right. And then will read up on how to use these things correctly before I dive into it.

Comment: My book code has an example of calling UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum, here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/e164b6d2007c502eae2d0dd158ee477ef288b7cb/bk2ch15p660EmbeddedAVKit/EmbeddedAVKit/ViewController.swift

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've decided to put this off until my knowledge of multithreading is significantly better.

Comment: You do not have to be multithreaded to use AVFoundation, and it is probably better not to be. But you _do_ have to understand asynchronous functions/methods, because _everything_ having to do with AVFoundation is asynchronous. Everything you want to do with video takes significant time, so AV Foundation does it all on a background thread and you proceed in a completion handler. There are excellent WWDC videos about this (and of course my book covers it).

Comment: Again thank you for that very much. It is pretty difficult to find good sources around for this framework. I guess what I meant to say was concurrency programming. Understanding when and why things are sent to backgrounds threads will probably help my writability when it comes to programming in AVFoundation